# Implement access control in same or separate layer?

Tags: architecture, access-control

I'm wondering what's the better approach for enforcing access control from an architectural perspective.

Is it best to do access control within the regular classes/methods, or is it better to implement it in a separate layer at a higher level?

I see the benefits of both. If it's in the same layer, there is absolutely no way to circumvent it (by accident), yet it may make the code more complex.
On the other hand, if it is in a separate layer, then the access control implementation becomes separate from the rest of the code, making it easier to test and reason about.

I'm leaning towards the separate-layer solution, but I'm not quite sure.

I would appreciate any thoughts or relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define 'layers' in your context?

A good reference (IMO) is how [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#overview) works in the Java world.  It plugs into a chain of Spring MVC filters, and ensures that authorization/authentication happens before allowing calls through, but it's not directly coupled to the application logic code.  You can still unit-test API's independently (unless you introduce explicit coupling by pulling Spring Security concerns into your code).  Do you see this as being in the same 'layer'?

I would be very wary of explicitly coding security checks into every single public method or API endpoint - it feels like a lot of duplication and something that can become unmaintainable very quickly.  As an alternative, you could look at using the [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern to wrap security-specific logic around your methods.

Lastly, if you are exposing a set of API's or microservices, an [API gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) would be an option for implementing security in a clearly-defined, separate layer.  This does mean that you would then need to explicitly prevent calls to your API's from any source other than the gateway (e.g. via firewall rules).